# How the following c outputs garbage?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   int d, a = 1 & 0 && (d=4);
   printf("%d\n", d);
   return 0;
}
```

According to the operator precedence () statement d should be assigned but in the above program logical and is executed first. d value is not assigned to 4. Please anyone help me to understand the above program. I have tried with gcc and some online compilers

Comment: `&&` is short-circuiting. In any case, operator precedence doesn't control order of evaluation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126127/operator-precedence-and-evaluation-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at `f() + g() * h()` first.

Precedence and associativity defines what is an operand of what. For example,  [C operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) tells us that

```
f() + g() * h()
```

means

```
f() + ( g() * h() )     # * has higher precedence than +
```

rather than

```
( f() + g() ) * h()     # If + had higher precedence than *
```

Notably, **precedence doesn't determine the order in which operands are evaluated.** In our example, the three functions could be called in any order, as long as the result of `g()` and the result of `h()` are multiplied together, and that the result of the multiplication is added to the result of `f()`.

---

Back to

```
1 & 0 && ( d = 4 )
```

Precedence and associativity simply tell us that the above is equivalent to the following:

```
( 1 & 0 ) && ( d = 4 )    # & has higher precedence than &&
```

---

**So what does this do?**

`&&` dictates that its right-hand side is only evaluated if its left-hand side is true. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) or short-circuiting.

`1 & 0` is false, so `d = 4` is never evaluated. This leaves `d` unchanged, and thus uninitialized.

Comment: If I change the statement iintto a = 1 || 1 & 0 && (d = 6) then it will turn into (1 || 1 & 0) && (d=6) now what happens d should be assigned to 6. But again the garbage value is stored in d.

Comment: No, it does not stores 6 to d. It agains print garabage value

Comment: int main()
{
    int d;
    int a = 1 || 1 & 0 && (d = 6);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", d);
    return 0;
}

Comment: testprint.c:6:24: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
    int a = 1 || 1 & 0 && (d = 6);
              ~~ ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
testprint.c:6:24: note: place parentheses around the '&&' expression to silence this warning
    int a = 1 || 1 & 0 && (d = 6);
                       ^
                 (               )
1 warning generated.

Compiler message no error

Comment: `1 || 1 & 0 && (d = 6)` is not equivalent to `(1 || 1 & 0) && (d=6)`, it is equivalent to `1 || ( ( 1 & 0 ) && (d = 6) )`, and we already established that `( 1 & 0 ) && (d = 6)` doesn't evaluate the RHS of the `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

- `1 & 0 && (d=4)` is evaluated like this: `(1 & 0) && (d=4)`
- `(1 & 0)` is 0
- because of [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45848954/898348) the right hand side of the `&&` operator is not evaluated
- therefore `d=4` is never evaluated
- therefore `d` is never assigned
- and therefore `d` contains garbage because local variables are not initialized

If you change `int d` to `int d = 42`, the output of your program will be `42`